# I want to use numbers in App Names for iOS Apps.Guidelines allow?

Tags: ios

I want to use numbers in App Name. Example Name of the App is 12Monkeys or c99Solutions. I did not see any App guidelines to disallow this. Will there be any acceptance issues if the numbers are used?

Comment: Have you searched the app store? I see a number of apps that start with 99

Answer (score 2):

There are applications with names including numbers and there is no rule against it, so **you can use numbers** in you application name. I would suggest keeping your application name around 11 characters or less in order to see the full name on your phone screen